# Splitting field condition for subset of isomorphism image

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field, and $K$ a finite extension of $F$. Suppose that for every isomorphism $h$ which domain $K$ that fixes $F$, we have $h(K)\subseteq K$. How can we show that $K$ is a splitting field of some polynomial in $F$?

Since $K$ is a finite extension of $F$, there exists $c\in K$ such that $K=F(c)$. Let $P(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $c$ over $F$. I think $K$ is a splitting field of $P$, but how to show it? It is not clear with isomorphism $h$ to use.

Comment: Is there a typo in the second sentence?  If $h\colon K\to K$ is an isomorphism, then necessarily $h(K) = K$.

Comment: @JimBelk Yes, there is a typo, which has just been corrected. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Kunal, I think that "isomorphism" here can be a little misleading, though some authors use that name. What you want, perhaps, is: "Let $\;\overline F\;$ be an algebraically closed field s.t.$\;F\subset K\subset \overline F\;$. Suppose that for every monomorphism $\;h:K\to\overline F\;$ fixing pointwise $\;F\;$  we have that $\;h(K)\subset K\;$ ..." In fact, you want to use the fact that the extension $\;K/F\;$ is normal (separability should, I believe, be given separatedly...). Also, not true in general the extension will be simple.